# force outgoing links as http vs https on secure domain? (htaccess?)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, http-redirect

I have forced a ecommerce site to be always in https, due to some issues with having only specific urls triggered as secure. I have used the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.vshoen.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But now my problem is all external links without www in the url open in https as well for some reason. Most of the time its not a problem but there are a few specific links that need to simply be http://url.com instead of http://www.url.com and for in this case they are not loading as its trying to open them as https://url.com

I was hoping there would be a resolution to this, this is a wordpress site if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should check the requested URL first to make sure it is one of those you want to redirect to HTTPS. An example of a valid URL for a redirection would be useful.

Comment: I can't reproduce any examples of this happening to me on your site. 
The Pinterest link up the top and various links on the resources page don't include the www, and all open as expected (unsecured, without www). This is in Chrome on Windows. I wouldn't expect this to be an htaccess issue, sounds more like a browser bug or browser plugin.

Can you give any more details about your setup, and examples of specific links on your site that are failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```